# Algorithm X Python Implementation

Tags: python, sudoku

I found a python implementation of algorithm X on an older, unmaintained web page. It works beautifully. The code is very concise and without comments. There is one piece that I am not grasping. I know it works, but I don't know how or why. Hoping the python programmers more advanced than myself can help.

In the code below "select" is being called, but what is happening to the return value. Furthermore, is "select" changing the values within X (i.e. X.pop(j))? Isn't "select" being passed a copy of X?

This code:

```
X, Y = exact_cover(X, Y)
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, n in enumerate(row):
            if n:
                select(X, Y, (i, j, n))
    for solution in solve(X, Y, []):
        for (r, c, n) in solution:
            grid[r][c] = n
        yield grid
```

Calls this function:

```
def select(X, Y, r):
    cols = []
    for j in Y[r]:
        for i in X[j]:
            for k in Y[i]:
                if k != j:
                    X[k].remove(i)
        cols.append(X.pop(j))
    return cols
```

Source: [https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eaassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html)

Autor: Ali Assaf

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but no, `select` isn't given a copy of `X`. It's given `X` and it's free to alter the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutable data types are passed as reference not copy. and yes X.pop() will change original X.

Comment: Thank you. I know that is simple, I should have looked at the docs to see the pass by ref. So I guess that code is ignoring the return value because its not needed at that point.